# Java Game of War not working as expected - fixed winner regardless of original deck values

Tags: java

Java program has fixed winner regardless of cards in both players decks.

The game of War starts with a shuffled deck of 52 that are distributed evenly (26 cards each) to both players (deck1 and deck2). For the number of rounds specified, the first card in each deck's array is compared. (The player may exit after every round). The winner takes both cards (values) and puts it at the bottom of the deck (end of listed values) (Arraylists are not allowed). The game ends when one deck has no cards. One of the decks consistently gets all the cards regardless of the original shuffled values and I don't understand why. All I could pinpoint is that the winner depended on the original assignment of cards from the array. The deck that obtained the first 26 cards always won.

Code show below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.exit;

public class War {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numTimePlay = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 0;

        if (numTimePlay < 1) {
            System.out.println("Error: invalid number");
            exit(0);
        }

        //starts game
        for (int m = 0; m < numTimePlay; m++) {

            //Each grouping of four represents a group of the same number arranged by suit
            int[] fullDeck = new int[52];
            for (int i = 0; i < fullDeck.length; i++) {
                fullDeck[i] = i + 1;
            }
            //Shuffled numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < fullDeck.length; i++) {
                int l = (int) (Math.random() * (52 - i));
                int temp1 = fullDeck[i];
                fullDeck[i] = fullDeck[l];
                fullDeck[l] = temp1;
            }

            //Split deck for players
            int[] deck1 = new int[52];
            int[] deck2 = new int[52];
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                deck2[i] = fullDeck[i];
            }
            for (int i = 26; i < fullDeck.length; i++) {
                deck1[i - 26] = fullDeck[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
                System.out.print(deck1[i]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
                System.out.print(deck2[i]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            //starting deck numbers
            int cards1 = 26;
            int cards2 = 26;

            while (deck1[0] != 0 && deck2[0] != 0) {
                //look it's the "starting" player
                int startingPlayer = (int) (Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? 1 : 2;
                boolean player = deck1[0] < deck2[0];

                //deck 1 moves over
                int value1 = deck1[0];
                for (int i  = 1; i < deck1.length; i++){
                    deck1[i-1] = deck1[i];
                }

                //deck 2 moves over
                int value2 = deck2[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < deck2.length; i++){
                    deck2[i-1] = deck2[i];
                }

                //cards added to winner's deck
                if (player) {
                    deck1[cards1-1] = value1;
                    deck1[cards1] = value2;
                    cards1++;
                    cards2--;
                }
                else{
                    deck2[cards2-1] = value2;
                    deck2[cards2] = value1;
                    cards2++;
                    cards1--;
                }
            }

                for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
                    System.out.print(deck1[i]+ " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
                System.out.print(deck2[i]+ " ");
                }
                if (cards1 == 0){
                    System.out.println("Player loses");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("CPU loses");
                }
                //Grab user input to use break if needed
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y/N");
                Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String yes = myScanner.next();
                if (!(yes.equals("Y"))){
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
                    exit(0);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: If your `for` loops for printing the contents of `deck1` and `deck2` are for testing or debugging, you might be interested in `Arrays.toString`: `System.out.println (Arrays.toString (deck1));` for example will print the contents of the array.

Comment: The card game, [War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game)), is played with a deck of playing cards which has four suits, i.e. Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts and Spades, where each suit has 13 cards with values from 2 to 14 (inclusive, assuming Aces are high). Shouldn't your [full] "deck" model an actual deck of [playing] cards?

Comment: If the `player` from `boolean player = deck1[0] < deck2[0];` is true, this means deck2 is the winner, however, in your if-condition `if(player) { ... cards1++; cards2--; }` it seems like you're giving the card to player1 instead of player2.  Am I misunderstanding something?  Shouldn't it be the other way?

Comment: Off-topic: Consider creating a `static` method for sorting. You can use it in future code. Consider using the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Off-topic: You could use one `for` loop to split the dek. Since you used two `for` loops to split the deck, consider twice using  [copyOfRange method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue! Since with this method of tie resolution, the king of diamonds can never be beaten, the player with "52" in their deck will always win. For some reason, the deck shuffling mechanism consistently put 52 in the first 26 cards, so that player always won. After making the math.random multiplied by 52 rather than 52-i, the 52 was more randomly distributed and both players won.

Comment: Maybe you could post your corrected code, so people can see exactly how you solved it?

Comment: @Abra I believe Seruloo changed `int l = (int) (Math.random() * (52 - i));` to `int l = (int) (Math.random() * (52));`